# Does the BlackBerry OS 4.x support Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blackberry

When I run my web app in the BlackBerry emulator 8320 I get an error about javascript not enabled. Does BlackBerry OS 4.x support javascript?

> " the requested action could not be
>   performed. Java script is not enabled
>   on this hand held".

Answer (score 2):

application -> browser -> options -> configuration, turn on javascript from there. It may not be enabled by default on the simulator.

I don't believe that it is enabled by default on phones, but it may be different now.

on browser version 4.5 and prior, there is no dynamic javascript.

Comment: Even though I was enabled the java script but now no issue. But now the alert box doesn't come?

Answer (score 1):

[There's a link to AJAX support on BB](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Blackberry-browser-support-for-AJAX/td-p/21370)